# I need a simple web server with a console

Tags: http-headers

My problem is I am adding an Ajax client to an existing RPC web service.  i have a PHP client that talks to it, a java jibx.POX client that talks  to it, a pure java http client that i wrote that talks to it, everything.  but when i try to put my jquery ajax client im working on at it, the server sees the connection, but doesn't receive any data.  same on the response, the service sends its error response xml and the ajax client says nothing came back.

what i need to debug this is a simple web server.  i want something that is a stand alone program.  where i can enter a port number and a start button.  point my ajax interface to it, and it displays in a text area all the information possible on the request.  then i can point one of my other interfaces to the same port and compare the two and hopefully figure out why 4 interfaces work and 1 doesn't.

does that exist out there somewhere?  maybe in one of your arsenals somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

OOPS, never mind, i found one.  TCPMon, its a java system a friend of mine emailed me a while ago.  does exactly this.

thanks